# How do I calculate the following surface area?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> I have encountered this problem during my vector calculus studies which I cannot seem to setup correctly. This is a paraphrasing of the question:
>
> Calculate the surface area of the surface $S$, a cone such that $z^2=x^2+y^2$, bounded above the disc
> $x^2+y^2\le4$.

---

What formula would I use to compute this, or what is the process to getting the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is to plot the region the exercise is talking about (it's just a cone with the vertex in the bottom at (0,0,0) and a it's top at z = 2) and solve for the triple integral that gives you the volume. That is $\displaystyle\int_{\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2 \leq z^2 \leq 4\}}dxdydz$.

Or if you're used to cylindrical coordinates, try those. They're much easier in this case.

Comment: Just realized you actually wanted the area. Sorry for that.

Comment: Try solving the surface integrals in the surfaces I talked you about before.

Comment: I am familiar with surface integrals but I am confused as to what my G(u, v) function would be in this case? Transforming this to cylindrical coordinates yields that r is bounded from 0-2 and z is bounded by r. Would these by my bounds for my function G(r, z)?

Comment: You have two distinct surfaces that needs separate integrals to solve. The first one is $\{^2+y^2=4,z=2\}$ which is a disk of radius 2. The second one is $\{x^2+y^2=z^2, 0 \leq z \leq 2\}$, which is the lateral surface of the cone. Both parametrization will help you deciding what are your needed functions. The second integral might be easier if done in cilydrincal coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The area of $S$ as described is infinite, since $z^2=x^2+y^2$ is a double cone that opens outward to positive and negative infinity. Perhaps you meant to include $z\ge0$, or equivalently $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? I'll assume that to be the case.

The standard choice of parameterization for $S$ would be one that relies on cylindrical coordinates.

$$\vec s(u,v)=\langle u\cos v,u\sin v,\sqrt{u^2\cos^2v+u^2\sin^2v}\rangle=\langle u\cos v,u\sin v,u\rangle$$

with $u\in[0,2]$ and $v\in[0,2\pi]$. Then the surface element is

$$\mathrm dS=\left\|\frac{\partial\vec s}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\vec s}{\partial v}\right\|\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv=\sqrt2\,u\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv$$

The area of $S$ is then

$$\iint_S\mathrm dS=\sqrt2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2u\,\mathrm du\,\mathrm dv=\boxed{4\sqrt2\,\pi}$$

Answer (score -1):

Here, given cone $$z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$ and as it is given that the required region is bounded above the disc $ \Rightarrow  z \in (0,2] $

You can solve the problem either by relying on the formula of lateral surface area $ S = \pi r l$ where $r =$ Radius, and $ l = $ slanted height.

Or you can use calculus.
Here I will use cylindrical coordinates.

My area element would be $dA = r d\theta dh \sec \frac{\pi}{4}$ ,Here $r = h$, so
$$ A = \sec \biggr (\frac{\pi}{4} \biggl )\int_0^2 \int^{2\pi}_0 h dr  d \theta $$

Your task is to figure out why there is $\sec \bigr (\frac{\pi}{4} \bigl )$ and $r = h$